# what is the use of mule-app-maven-plugin?

Tags: maven, mulesoft, mule4

What is this mule-app-maven-plugin is used for ?
https://docs.mulesoft.com/release-notes/mule-app-maven-plugin/mule-app-maven-plugin-release-notes

and also i see maven-clean-plugin ?if we use `mvn clean` in the command isnt it sufficient do we need to add this plugin in the pom.xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a legacy Maven plugin used to build Mule 3.x applications. In Mule 4 it has been replaced by the newer Mule Maven Plugin: https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.3/mmp-concept